# Page redirection for user who do not have role privilege

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2005

I am using VS2005 C# ASP.NET 2.0.

I have used role management in the `web.config` with the following code snippet:

```
`<location path="Administrator">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="Administrator"/>
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>`
```

However, when a user with no roles assigned tries to login, they are redirected to the custom error page which I have defined:

`<customErrors defaultRedirect="~/Error/UnexpectedError.aspx" mode="On">
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/PageNotFound.aspx"/>
        </customErrors>`

My `defaultRedirect` page are for handling unexpected errors in my code.

May I know if there is an error code which I can use to redirect **users who are registered but have no role assigned** tries to login to another page instead of my default error page ?

Comment: I would suggest adding a role to the user anyway, e.g. "NotApproved" and in the login page/control redirect them to wherever you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the defaultUrl attribute of the form tag in the web config file that way every time a user that has not enough privilages to access your files will be redirect to the defaultUrl Page.